Retis evaluation with Openpathsampling
Dear Users of Openpathsamling !
I am an old user of OPS, and I need to evaluate my RETIS calculation. I have done this before, back in 2021, but I was back then still using the old NETCDF (.nc) storage files.
The format of the storage changed since, and I am now trying to use the my old scripts for the same task, but run into various problems.
One of them is the following: when I use my old OPS installation from 2021, I apply the monkey patch and I manage to load my storage - however OPS is unable to access the stored CV values form the database and starts to recompute them on saved snapshots one by one. However this starts using increasingly more memory and slows down unbearably.
So I wonder if it is possible to perform a RETIS evaluation using the new database files? Or did something fundamental change in the evaluation process?
Thank you in advance. I am happy to provide more details to solve this problem step by step.
Gyorgy

+1 but I've edited it to conform to the one question per post policy: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5
